# Drop down immediately disappears after hover in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following code:

```css
/****  DropDown Css  ******/

.inner_menu ul#nav > li span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  background: url(../images/drp_arw_dwn.png) no-repeat center;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.inner_menu ul#nav > li:hover span {
  background: url(../images/drp_arw.png) no-repeat center;
}

.inner_menu ul#nav > li:hover .subnav {
  display: block;
}

.subnav {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 18px;
  display: none;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  border-style: solid; 
  border-width: 5px; 
  border-color:#2c91da
}

.subnav ul {
  background: #333;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.subnav ul li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.subnav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.subnav ul li:hover a {
  color: #2c91da;
  display: block;
}

/******************  Nav Menu  *****************/

.header .wrapper:after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.dashboard_page {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 42px 0;

}

.dashboard_page .wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

.dashboard_page:after {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 370px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background: #f7f8f9;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.inner_menu {
  margin: 7px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

.inner_menu ul#nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.inner_menu ul#nav > li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 52px;
  line-height: 52px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  position: relative;
}

.inner_menu ul#nav > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #2f2f2f;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 27px;
  border-style: solid; 
  border-width: 5px;
}

.inner_menu ul#nav > li:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 38px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -19px;
  content: "";
  background: url(../images/menu_arw.png) no-repeat;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: -35px;
  z-index: 9;
  display: none;
}

.inner_menu ul#nav > li:hover:after {
  display: block;
}

.inner_menu ul#nav > li.active:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner_menu">
  <div class="toggle"></div>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Trackers</a>
      <div class="subnav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is that in internet explorer, when I try to move my cursor below the element to click on the dropdown, it disappears and I am unable to click it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a code snippet with an example that replicates your problem?

Comment: Is there space between the <li> and the dropdown? (so you are effectively hovering off of the <li> before hovering onto the dropdown.

Comment: @TonyTambe I added borders between the .subnav and link.  As you can see there is no space.  What css value can I change to eliminate the space if there is one?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this CSS item:

.header .wrapper:after{ position:absolute; bottom:-33px; width:100%; height:34px; content:""; left:0; background:url(../images/shadow-bg.png) no-repeat center; background-size:100% auto; pointer-events:none}

The attribute bottom should be a higher negative number.  -150px worked for me.  I changed it to this:

.header .wrapper:after{ position:absolute;

> bottom:-150px

; width:100%; height:34px; content:""; left:0; background:url(../images/shadow-bg.png) no-repeat center; background-size:100% auto; pointer-events:none}

Answer (score -1):

Let's break it down:

1. You hover over '.inner_menu ul#nav > li:hover'
2. The 'display' is set to 'block' for '.subnav'.
3. You move your mouse until it moves outside of the actual link (The one that says "Trackers")
4. The selector '.inner_menu ul#nav > li:hover' no longer applies, since you are no longer hovering over the link.
5. The background is unset.

If you move the .subnav close to the link (No spaces!) it should work better.

Here is a link to a navigation bar that uses CSS only: http://www.cssnewbie.com/easy-css-dropdown-menus/

You might want to use JavaScript for more advanced functionality.

Some limitations for CSS:

- No spaces, if you sub-menu is not RIGHT next to the link to it, it probably won't work (Or would at least be very hard to implement)
- No advanced fading, clicking or other events, just hovering.

Comment: I added borders and it shows that the .subnav touches the link border?  Do you know which value I can change to make it overlap if they aren't currently close enough?

Comment: It works fine in Internet Explorer 11 for me now when I run the snippet